# disabledBinding on ember component

Tags: ember.js, handlebars.js

normally I would use disabledBinding=isNotEditing to toggle a select read-only status, using {{view Ember.Select disabledBinding=isNotEditing}}

If I wanted to use a standard select (not ember-select) in a component, how would I go about binding disabledBinding=isNotEditing to the component ?

```
{{my-select .. disabledBinding=isNotEditing}}
```

does not work

Comment: Could you put together a jsFiddle?

Answer (score 1):

I got round it by using this:

```
 App.FixedSelectComponent = Ember.Component.extend({
    disabledObserver: function() {
        this.$("#select1").select2("enable", !this.get('disabled'));
    }.observes('disabled'),
 },
```

and calling the component by

```
{{fixed-select options=stateList selectedValue=stateID disabled=isNotEditing}}
```

it seems to work, but I don't know if it is appropriate ...

Answer (score 0):

Most likely you'd want to have `MySelect` `extend` `Ember.Select` so that it picks up all of the bindings.

```
App.MySelectView = Ember.Select.extend({...});
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer - but as mentioned, I'm wanting to use select2 (https://github.com/ivaynberg/select2) not the ember-select. I don't think that extending Ember.Select will help in this case.

Comment: Actually, you didn't mention select2 in your question, and your answer that mentions it wasn't here when I answered your question.  Why are you trying to avoid the Ember select?  Why not extend Ember select and then use the `didInsertElement` hook to trigger select2?

Comment: yes, my apologies - I simply mentioned that I didn't want to use ember select, and didn't mention select2 specifically. I am wanting to have search / filter capabilities and multiple selection and rather than trying to roll my own thought that it would be better to use selects that are way, way better than anything I could do. I settled on either chosen or select2 and was wondering how to make them more ember-like (hence the component part)